# Initializing a reference with a temporary object

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I ran into a bug the other day, which more or less came down to this:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(T x) : x_(x) {}
  T& x_;
};

int main() {
  T x;
  auto foo = Foo(x);
}
```

This is pretty silly. When `Foo` is constructed, its argument is passed by value. Once constructed, the argument is likely popped off the stack, leaving the `Foo` object with a reference to garbage data. I might be wrong in my understanding here, but that's how I see this working.

Is there any reason to ever do this? I've compiled this code with a GCC ARM compiler, a proprietary TI ARM compiler and MSVC, and none of them give any warnings or errors. I can't for the life of me figure out a place where this makes sense, but I usually don't have much confidence in myself when I'm disagreeing with three compilers.

Am I totally out to lunch here? Is there a good reason to do this, and if not, is there a reason that compilers couldn't detect this?

Comment: Try a higher warning level; `-Wall`, for example.

Comment: It's not a bug. You understand it right. You may use references when designing shared data objects. It's not a compilation error when reference becomes invalid. If compiler detects it, it can just give you a warning.

Comment: clang++: "main.cpp:4:17: warning: binding reference member `x_` to stack allocated parameter `x` [-Wdangling-field]"

Comment: The reference data member can be used inside the constructor (body and mem-initializer-list). If you call a function there that expects/requires a reference member, this might be useful. It could also involve a base class which contains that reference data member.